# Why did Victor Pelevin's books fail to get such popularity as they had in Russia?

Tags: russian-language, reception, victor-pelevin

Victor Pelevin is presumably the most best-selling contemporary writer in Russia. Several of his books have been [translated](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=pelevin&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) to English, but none of them became even slightly popular among the Western audience. Why is it so given that Pelevin's books are extremely popular in Russia? There certainly must be some other reasons apart from simply cultural context because, for instance, S.N.U.F.F. storyline takes place in a quite globalistic intercultural environment.

Comment: This question invites answers that would be extremely speculative and opinion-based, which makes it unsuitable for the Stack Exchange network. I suggest that you [find a forum](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/768/2191) to ask it there.